# Performance issue in entity framework

Tags: mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, asp.net-core-webapi

I have some DB models:

```
 public class SomeEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class Schedule
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeRange> Monday { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeRange> Tuesday { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeRange> Wednesday { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeRange> Thursday { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeRange> Friday { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeRange> Saturday { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeRange> Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

And when I run:

```
 var entity = _dbContext.SomeEntity
                .Include(p => p.Addresses)
                .Include(p => p.Emails)
                .Include(p => p.Phones)
                .Include(p => p.Schedule)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Monday)
                .Include(p => p.Schedule)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Tuesday)
                .Include(p => p.Schedule)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Wednesday)
                .Include(p => p.Schedule)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Thursday)
                .Include(p => p.Schedule)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Friday)
                .Include(p => p.Schedule)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Saturday)
                .Include(p => p.Schedule)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.Sunday)
            return entity;
```

It tooks a very long time to execute. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should use Database Indexes, and you may also want to apply a `.Where` clause because right now you are taking in ALL rows of SomeEntity with ALL their related values from other tables.

Comment: Even with `.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);` it took around 4162 ms

Comment: Your table definitions + index definitions are needed to answer this question. Also specify which DBMS or Datasource you are using (Access? Excel? MySQL? Oracle? Sql Server?) Drop the less relevant tags and add a proper DBMS tag.

Comment: You can't keep adding `Include`s and expect the query to remain snappy. It looks like the `Schedule` part of the model needs further normalization. Having all these separate days doesn't look well.

Comment: I use 5.5.52-MariaDB. Tables have been autogenerated by code. `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();`
I see many queries in logs. Can I get it all with 1 query?

Comment: You might consider looking at this link related to the MySql EFCore support, as it appears no direct mariadb connectors but this one for mysql might improve your timings, but that query is really ugly... https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,664024

Comment: One step could to have `Schedule` have a days collection in which days have a day number.

Comment: Hello, Do you have a proper sql query that you want to implement in LINQ and EF Core? From what i see this statement creates a lot of JOINS and without a proper raw sql statement i dont think that there is much to do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have way too many includes. There is currently no option to optimize it directly (include with filters will be in next version of ef core 2.1). If you really need all that data, you should use rawquery.